# Figuring out this pattern in assembly

Tags: assembly

I keep seeing the following pattern in assembly and I was wondering how to translate this into pseudocode, as I don't quite understand what is going on here. I have put my comments next to it as a suspicion of what's happening.

Question:

Presumably, they are part of a function that takes two parameters that are two doubles. Then it creates an array of 2 numbers array[2] and loads these doubles into the array. Is that what is happening?

```
8049a73:       ba 8d ae 04 08          mov    $0x804ae8d,%edx // put two numbers into register edx, %d %d (found on gdb)
8049a78:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax // take parameter 1 and put into register eax
8049a7b:       8d 4d f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%ecx // take a local variable and put this into register ecx ???
8049a7e:       89 4c 24 0c             mov    %ecx,0xc(%esp) // move ecx onto the top of the stack ???
8049a82:       8d 4d f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%ecx // move this other local variable and put this onto the top of the stack
8049a85:       89 4c 24 08             mov    %ecx,0x8(%esp) // move this variable to the top of the stack too
8049a89:       89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp) // from the edx register, put that at the top of the stack too
8049a8d:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp) // then compare what is at eax with the address of esp ???
8049a90:       e8 db f1 ff ff          call   8048c70 <sscanf@plt>
8049a95:       83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax // compare value in the register eax against constant 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` means integer, not double. Read the documentation for `sscanf`.
The code is doing a `sscanf` invocation, setting up the parameters on the stack as per the applicable calling convention (4 arguments starting from `(%esp)`), then checks the returned value.

The function has 1 incoming argument at `0x8(%ebp)` (I will call this `arg_08`) and two local variables at `-0x10(%ebp)` and `-0xc(%ebp)` (I will call these `local_10` and `local_0c`, respectively). As such, the equivalent C code is:

`if (sscanf(arg_08, "%d %d", &local_0c, &local_10) == 2)`

Comment: So when you say it is setting up the parameters on the stack, these are the lines you are referring to - e.g. 8049a7e:       89 4c 24 0c             mov    %ecx,0xc(%esp)

Comment: Also, isn't the comparison really only what is loaded in just eax, which is the first argument. So the comparison would be if (arg_08 > 2 || arg_08 < 2)?

Comment: This is absolutely right. Older compilers would be `push`ing  args on the stack. Newer `gcc` versions allocate a chunk of memory with one instruction and move the arguments to the correct locations in sequential order. This is faster than `push`es.

Comment: The last assembly statement compares 2 against the return value of `sscanf` which is in `%eax`.

Comment: @Jester 've added a question about an assignment I'm on - would be very grateful if you could offer a similar explanation there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043157/difficult-to-interpret-what-is-going-on-in-assembly-for-complicated-binary-bomb

Answer (score 1):

From your last question...

```
int *array[3]; // Moving from registers to %esp 
int return_value = sscanf(param1, "%d %d %d", array[0], array[1], array[2]); 
if(return_value == 3): // If there were 3 integers... see sscanf documentation
...
```

You can figure out a lot with a couple of clues. For example, we now know the function prototype looks roughly like this:

```
level_3(char* param1 ...);
```

because we know the prototype for sscanf:

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

Also, remember the rule that the `%eax` register holds the return values for the called function, in this case sscanf, so the comparison is basically a check whether or not param1 has 3 integers in it. Also, moving to some offset of `%esp` is setting up args for the function-to-be-called;  `-%ebp` is for local variables, `+%ebp` is for the function's own parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's putting function arguments onto the stack to prepare a subroutine call.
Most x86-C-ABIs (application binary interface, calling convention) require arguments to functions like `int foo(int arg1, float arg2, char *arg3)` to be put on the stack, in reverse order:

```
push arg3
push arg2
push arg1
call foo
```

An optimizing compiler can instead write

```
sub 12, %esp
mov arg3, 8(%esp)
mov arg2, 4(%esp)
mov arg1, (%esp)
call foo
```

This can be faster, because `%esp` is not modified by each instruction, thus on pipelined machines there is less need to delay operand fetch for the next instruction that needs `%esp`

Comment: The "reverse order" is misleading, the calling convention says they should be on the stack in normal left-to-right order with increasing memory addresses. The reversing is only due to the pushes.

Comment: I'd say it's because of the downward-growing stack, but that's pretty much the same...